# Multiplicação de 3 matrizes

Tags: java, funções, matriz

Tenho que fazer a multiplicação de 3 matrizes com a validação de que dá mesmo para fazer, em uma função. Estou tentando fazer a matriz 1 e 2 primeiro e pegar o resultado para fazer a 3. Mas está dando errado e também não consigo chamar o resultado no main.

```
 public static int[][] mult(int linha, int coluna, int linha2, int coluna2, int linha3, int coluna3, int[][] matriz, int[][] matriz2, int[][] matriz3) {

            if(matriz[0].length == matriz2.length){
                int[][] matrizR = new int[linha][coluna2];
             
                for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < coluna2; j++)
                        for(int k = 0; k < linha2; k++)
                            matrizR[i][j] = matriz[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
                }
                return matrizR;
            }
            if(matrizR[0].length == matriz3.length){
               int[][] resultado = new int[linha][coluna3];
              
               for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
                   for(int j = 0; j < coluna3; j++)
                       for(int k = 0; k < linha2; k++)
                           resultado[i][j] = matrizR[i][k] * matriz3[k][j];
               }
               return resultado;
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para multiplicar 2 matrizes, a quantidade de colunas da primeira deve ser igual à quantidade de linhas da segunda. Ou seja, se a primeira matriz é M x N (M linhas e N colunas), a segunda deve ser N x P (N linhas e P colunas) e o resultado será uma matriz M x P (M linhas e P colunas).

De qualquer forma, eu acho mais fácil fazer um método que multiplica 2 matrizes, e aí você pode usar para multiplicar quantas quiser depois. E o algoritmo está errado, no último `for` você tem que somar ao valor da célula, mas você está sobrescrevendo-o ([veja aqui o algoritmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)).

Nos casos abaixo não estou verificando se todas as linhas da matriz possuem a mesma quantidade de colunas (estou assumindo que isso já foi verificado antes). E também não precisa passar a quantidade de linhas e colunas, pois é possível obter isso das próprias matrizes:

```
// multiplica apenas 2 matrizes
public static int[][] mult(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    if (m1[0].length != m2.length) { // se a quantidade de coluunas de m1 é diferente da quantidade de linhas de m2
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Não é possível multiplicar, tamanhos incompatíveis");
    }

    int[][] result = new int[m1.length][m2[0].length];
    for (int lin = 0; lin < result.length; lin++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < result[lin].length; col++) {
            int valor = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m2.length; i++) {
                valor += m1[lin][i] * m2[i][col]; // soma ao valor ("+=" em vez de "=")
            }
            result[lin][col] = valor;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Então, se você quiser multiplicar 3 matrizes, basta usar o método acima, multiplicando de 2 em 2:

```
// multiplica 3 matrizes
public static int[][] multiplicaTrezMatrizes(int[][] m1, int[][] m2, int[][] m3) {
    // primeiro multiplica m1 e m2
    int[][] result = mult(m1, m2);

    // depois multiplica por m3
    return mult(result, m3);
}
```

Ou, se quiser fazer um método genérico que recebe qualquer quantidade de matrizes:

```
public static int[][] multiplicaVariasMatrizes(int[][]... matrizes) {
    int[][] result = matrizes[0]; // pega a primeira matriz
    for (int i = 1; i < result.length; i++) { // vai multiplicando as matrizes
        result = mult(result, matrizes[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

// e no main:
int[][] m1 = { new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 4 }, new int[] { 5, 6 } };
int[][] m2 = { new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
int[][] m3 = { new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 4 }, new int[] { 5, 6 }, new int[] { 7, 8 } };

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(multiplicaVariasMatrizes(m1, m2, m3)));
```